# DL4j - Rounded floating points when converting from Java Array to INDArray

Tags: dl4j

Converting from Java array to INDArray causes values to be rounded to nearest approximation

**Actual behaviour**

From Java Array -
[0.0025249954778701, -0.0046458570286632, 0.0052295182831585, -0.0014667856739834, -0.0044226963073015, 0.0073519190773368, -0.0003814829979092, -0.0084274942055345, -0.0040481365285814, 0.0082860253751278]

To INDArray-
[0.00, -0.00, 0.01, -0.00, -0.00, 0.01, -0.00, -0.01, -0.00, 0.01]

**Expected behaviour**

From Java Array -
[0.0025249954778701, -0.0046458570286632, 0.0052295182831585, -0.0014667856739834, -0.0044226963073015, 0.0073519190773368, -0.0003814829979092, -0.0084274942055345, -0.0040481365285814, 0.0082860253751278]

To INDArray-
[0.0025249954778701, -0.0046458570286632, 0.0052295182831585, -0.0014667856739834, -0.0044226963073015, 0.0073519190773368, -0.0003814829979092, -0.0084274942055345, -0.0040481365285814, 0.0082860253751278]

**Below is the code**

```
var (left, right) = inoc.splitAt(7840)
var bias :INDArray = Nd4j.create(right);
var weights :INDArray = Nd4j.create(left);
```

Comment: Welcome to SA. FYI, there are lots of rules etc when posting and people will likely vote this question down because its trivial to solve. Secondly, you didn't even show your code that created this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default data type is float in the latest version.
This is due to memory reasons.

Please ensure you create your arrays with double precision if that's what you're desiring.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Creating an INDArray with double precision did not work in my case, I still see values rounded off. Also, I would like to set gradients of a model which accepts only floating points, therefore, even if it converts to double pointer preserving rounded off values, it cannot be much of use. Any idea if I can convert to floating point INDArray while preserving the actual values?

Comment: The underlying values should be preserved actually as long as everything is a double array.  You can get the data out with array.data().asDouble(); if you want a double vector. Check those values or check it in a debugger to see lower precision values. If everything is already double, the numbers don't just disappear, but the toStrings() may sometimes be rounded.